# @Transactional only on one method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions

I need to make a @Scheduled method that has a list of schemas and for each schema, deletes rows from 2 tables.

```
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {
    List<String> presentSchemas = getPresentSchemas();
    for (String schema : presentSchemas) {
        deleteFromCustomerTables(schema);
    }
}
```

I've defined deleteFromCustomerTables as    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) and inside it i use the EntityManager to delete rows from 2 tables.

In order to make it work i need to add @Transactional to scheduleFixedDelayTask, otherwise i recive a TransactionRequiredException.

My problem is that i do not want the whole scheduler to be @Transactional, if something goes wrong in one schema i do not want to do a rollback of all schemas.

I've also tried without @Transactional and with :

```
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
    //exec delete
    t.commit();
    session.close();
```

But i still recieve TransactionRequiredException.
Do you have a solution?

Comment: If you don't want to roll back all the changes then you can just put the transactional code in try-catch block, the one with error will fail and the loop will try for other till the list ends.

Comment: even if I define scheduleFixedDelayTask as @Transactional and put try-catch around deleteFromCustomerTables(schema), it stills rollback with  error "Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have to be sure that you configured the transaction manager something like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionConfig {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager();
  }
}
```

- You have to be sure that method deleteFromCustomerTables is not in the same component, something like this:

```java
@Component
class Component1 {
   void scheduleFixedDelayTask(){...}
}

@Component
class Component2 {
   void deleteFromCustomerTables(){...}
}
```

> But at a very high level, Spring creates proxies for classes that
> declare @Transactional on the class itself or on members. The proxy is
> mostly invisible at runtime. It provides a way for Spring to inject
> behaviors before, after, or around method calls into the object being
> proxied. Transaction management is just one example of the behaviors
> that can be hooked in. Security checks are another. And you can
> provide your own, too, for things like logging. So when you annotate a
> method with @Transactional, Spring dynamically creates a proxy that
> implements the same interface(s) as the class you're annotating. And
> when clients make calls into your object, the calls are intercepted
> and the behaviors injected via the proxy mechanism.

Comment: Thank you very much! My problem was using the same Component! Creating a second component solved the problem.